# How to mix glass and emission shader

Tags: glass, emission

I want to mix a glass and an emission shader. The goal is to create a window, which is seethrough but at the same time the light source. Normally I'd just use an HDRI and the glass shader to illuminate the room, but sadly this is not an option, as the program used to render the scene has an issue with light coming through other objects. I tried using a mixer and just plugging in the emission and glass shader but the outcome is a milky window and not enough light. The lower I set the emission strength, the better the sheerness of the window. [image] As you can see, the scene is very dark. I'd love to find a way, where I won't have to compensate for the missing window light by using the lamps.

Comment: Try using an Add Shader and add just a little bit of emission strength

Comment: Thanks for the quick help!

Comment: "as the program used to render the scene has an issue with light coming through other objects"  The right way to do this is going to depend on what you're using to render.  Materials, and techniques for them, are rarely compatible between different rendering engines.

Comment: I know alot of archviz artists specifically avoid using actual glass materials if they can avoid it. It's already hard enough getting interiors to look good and the extra noise, caustics, extra render time for something that is essentially invisible in the end render. Consider if it's even absolutely necessary to have glass in every one of these renders. You might be able to get away with just leaving that area empty.

Comment: The program used to render the scene is Mitsuba. Sadly the surface texture is of importance, so simply not having glass in the windows is not an option. But thank you for your advice!